# Can i upgrade my ubuntu (unity 16.10) using live usb of succeeding version (17.04) of different ubuntu flavor (say ubuntu gnome)

Tags: unity, gnome, upgrade

I have ubuntu 16.10, alongside I install gnome 3 desktop. since then I never use the unity. If I plan to install ubuntu gnome in version 17.04 by LiveUSB. can I Upgrade my current ubuntu not losing all my setting and safely eliminating the unity desktop?

Comment: You can, yes. My preferred method is upgrading the system to the following release of the installed system, and then installing the Ubuntu GNOME stack, and then removing the one I had before. (Not an answer because I don't have the commands to do this at hand.)

Comment: If you don't use Unity, then remove that DE today and install Ubuntu Gnome today. The release-upgrade seems irrelevant. You don't need a LiveUSB to remove Unity-related packages nor to install Ubuntu Gnome packages.